# Mac server in order to compile obj-c projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, compilation

Is it possible to write an obj-C code with any text editor and then upload it to Mac server to compile it using Xcode??
I know that it is possible to compile your project using Xcode without open it something like use some command lines, but I am not sure is it possible to make it a server and then upload any obj-c code!

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your projects from the command line using the [`xcodebuild`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/) command.  Automating your builds is another story altogether: you'll need to set up your server to download the updated source code (typically via version control, e.g. `svn update` or `p4 sync`), do the build, and then upload the builds results somehwere (e.g. check into version control).

Doing this is non-trivial, and there's a lot of software out there, such as [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/home.aspx), to help make this easier, although FinalBuilder is Windows software so probably isn't what you want.

Comment: +1 because we do this at my place of employment, but FYI, `xcodebuild` requires having a fully-configured .xcodeproj file.  If you just want to compile some .h and .m files, `gcc` or `clang` will work just fine.

Comment: what if I want to submit projects made by another IDE (not Xcode)?

Comment: @alex CSD - then you can't use `xcodebuild` and must use `gcc` or `clang`